# Django raw sql insert query in triple quotation: Django interprets null values from ajax request data as None column

Tags: django, reactjs, postgresql, django-rest-framework

I am working on a Django/React project. Using `DRF`, I am throwing an API route for performing SQL queries in my `PostgreSQL` database. But I am having issues with my current code setup.

I have setup my `INSERT` query in the API as `raw queries (using cursor)` enclosed in a triple quote multi-line string `"""INSERT..."""`, then format my values using string formatting `%s`. In my API, I capture each data from the request body into a variable. Everything works fine if all request data are filled. But, if it is `null`, Django obviously assigns `None` to the variable.

Now back to my sql query, Django will treat the null `%s` as `None` and as a `table column` instead of a correct null value, thus throwing a `ProgrammingError` *`column "none" does not exist`*.

Here are sample codes:

**React Frontend**

```
const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('')
const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('')
const [middleName, setMiddleName] = useState('')
const [nameExtn, setNameExtn] = useState('')
const [sex, setSex] = useState('')
const [civilStatus, setCivilStatus] = useState('')
const [bloodType, setBloodType] = useState('')
const [height, setHeight] = useState('')
const [weight, setWeight] = useState('')

const newPersonalInfo = (token, data) => {
    let endpoint = "/jobnet/api/profile/pds/basic/personal/"
    let lookupOptions = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Token ${token}`
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        credentials: 'include'
      }
    fetch(endpoint, lookupOptions)
    .then(res=>res.json())
    .then(function(info){
     console.log(info)
    })
    .catch(err=>console.log(err));
}

const handleNewPersonalInfo = () => {
    newPersonalInfo(props.user.token, {
        firstname: firstName,
        lastname: lastName,
        middlename: middleName,
        extension: nameExtn,
        birthdate: selectedDate,
        sex: sex,
        civilstatus: civilStatus,
        bloodtype: bloodType,
        height: height,
        weight: weight,
    })
}

...

return(
    <Button
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        onClick={handleNewPersonalInfo}
    >
        SAVE
    </Button>
)
```

**Django API (DRF)**

```
class APIListCreate__PersonalInfo(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    try:
        serializer_class = PDSBasicPersonalInfoSerializer
        permission_classes  = (jobnet_permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
        authentication_classes = (knox_TokenAuthentication,)
    except Exception as e:
        traceback.print_exc()

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        if user and user.is_authenticated:
            query = ("""
                SELECT
                    bsinfo.firstname,
                    bsinfo.middlename,
                    bsinfo.surname,
                    bsinfo.birthdate,
                    bsinfo.sex,
                    bsinfo.extention,
                    bsinfo.civilstatus,
                    bsinfo.height_m,
                    bsinfo.weight_kg,
                    bsinfo.bloodtype,
                    bsinfo.photo_path
                FROM jobnet_app.basicinfo bsinfo
                WHERE
                id=%s
            """ % user.id)
            return raw_sql_select(query, "default")
        else:
            return None

    def get(self, request):
        data = [
            {
                "first_name": col.firstname,
                "middle_name": col.middlename,
                "last_name": col.surname,
                "name_extension": col.extention,
                "birthdate": col.birthdate,
                "sex": col.sex,
                "civil_status": col.civilstatus,
                "height": col.height_m,
                "weight": col.weight_kg,
                "blood_type": col.bloodtype,
                "photo_path": col.photo_path
            } for col in self.get_queryset()[1]
        ]
        return Response(data[0])

    def post(self, request):
        try:
            user = request.user.id
            firstname = request.data.get('firstname') or ''
            middlename = request.data.get('middlename') or ''
            lastname = request.data.get('lastname') or ''
            birthdate = request.data.get('birthdate') or ''
            sex = request.data.get('sex') or ''
            extension = request.data.get('extension') or ''
            civilstatus = request.data.get('civilstatus') or ''
            height_m = request.data.get('height') or 0
            weight_kg = request.data.get('weight') or 0
            bloodtype = request.data.get('bloodtype') or ''
            query = ("""
                START TRANSACTION;
                    INSERT INTO jobnet_app.basicinfo (
                        id,
                        firstname,
                        middlename,
                        surname,
                        birthdate,
                        sex,
                        extention,
                        civilstatus,
                        height_m,
                        bloodtype,
                        weight_kg
                    )
                    VALUES (%s,'%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s',%s,'%s',%s);
            """ % (
                    user,
                    firstname,
                    middlename,
                    lastname,
                    birthdate,
                    sex,
                    extension,
                    civilstatus,
                    height_m,
                    bloodtype,
                    weight_kg
                )
            )
            unformatted_query_result = raw_sql_insert(query, "default")
            if unformatted_query_result:
                raw_sql_commit("default")
                return Response({
                    "success": True,
                    "message": "Your basic personal information has been updated successfully."
                }, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            else:
                raw_sql_rollback("default")
                return Response({
                    "success": False,
                    "message": "There was a problem updating your personal information."
                }, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        except Exception as e:
            traceback.print_exc()
            return Response({
                "success": False,
                "message":"Internal System Error: " + str(e)
            }, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

With above setup, I get such error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Acer\Envs\adnwebsite-react\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 83, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "none" does not exist
LINE 4: ...on','2002-03-18T06:18:45.284Z','Male','','Single',None,'B+',...
                                                             ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PGADN\Projects\pgadn-v2-website\adnwebsite\reactify\utils.py", line 17, in raw_sql_insert
    cn.execute(query)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\Envs\adnwebsite-react\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\Envs\adnwebsite-react\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\Envs\adnwebsite-react\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\Envs\adnwebsite-react\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\Envs\adnwebsite-react\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\Acer\Envs\adnwebsite-react\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 83, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "none" does not exist
LINE 4: ...on','2002-03-18T06:18:45.284Z','Male','','Single',None,'B+',...
```

I am using:

1. Django 2.0.6
2. Django Rest Framework 3.10.3
3. PostgreSQL 11.3 (on my development machine) and PostgreSQL 12.1 (on production server) (although the error above has not yet been replicated to the server)

**Note:** `raw_sql_select`, `raw_sql_insert`, `raw_sql_commit`, `raw_sql_rollback` are simply custom-made helper functions which handle the actual cursor execution in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **SQL Parameters** instead of `%` to create your insert script.

For example-

```
# **WRONG** 
>>> cur.execute("INSERT INTO numbers VALUES (%s, %s)" % (10, 20)) 

# **correct**
>>> cur.execute("INSERT INTO numbers VALUES (%s, %s)", (10, 20))
```

You must be using `cusrsor.execute` in your helper functions. Pass the values as a list as a second parameter in the `cusrsor.execute` as shown above.

Folow this [link](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) to read more.

Comment: Thanks man! This solution is way more appropriate and easier to implement...